# Could not open the confirmation box using javascript and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing some issues. I am  trying to open the confirmation box using javascript click event but getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getUID is not a function
    at Confirmation.init (VM8904 bootstrap-confirmation.js:151)
    at new Confirmation (VM8904 bootstrap-confirmation.js:16)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (VM8904 bootstrap-confirmation.js:427)
    at Function.each (VM8902 jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (VM8902 jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.confirmation (VM8904 bootstrap-confirmation.js:419)
    at getConirmation (VM8906:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (VM8987:14)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div onclick="getConirmation();">
    <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="top"></span></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function getConirmation() {
      $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        // other options
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I need when user will click on that icon the confirmation box will open on the top of that icon. [Here is my plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/twxi39pznNXUyQnFKnOy?p=preview). Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using bootstrap version 3.0 + and bootstrap-confirmation doesn't support 3.0 version. So you can either downgrade your bootstrap version or use another library from [here](https://github.com/tavicu/bs-confirmation).

Bug description [here](https://github.com/ethaizone/Bootstrap-Confirmation/issues/20).

Answer (score 0):

Reading I've been testing your Plunker code, and the main problem is with the jQuery and Bootstrap versions you're using. According to boostraps-confirmation documentation, you need...

```
jQuery >= 1.9
Bootstrap Popover >= 3.2 (included in bootstrap.js)
```

I've changed to this...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

... and works without problems.

On the other hand, to use this plugin you don't need to create the onClick event in the element where you want to apply it. Just execute the plugin to apply it to all elements that have `data-toggle='confirmation'`.

Putting all together...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="bottom"></span></p>
  </div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
          rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
      });
  });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

***NOTE***: I leave the CDN just to show the versions I've used. Of course, you can download the libraries to your project if you prefer it.